# Get all dates as list for given month and year in scala

Tags: scala

I tired to write function to get all dates as list for given month and year as follow

```
def allDaysForYear(year: String , month:String): List[(String, String, String)] = {
  val daysInYear = if(Year.of(year.toInt).isLeap) 366 else 365
  for {
    day <- (1 to daysInYear).toList
    localDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(year.toInt, day)
    month = localDate.getMonthValue
    dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth
  } yield (year, month.toString, dayOfMonth.toString)
}
```

What I expect is following list

```
List(2016-10-01,2016-10-02,.....ect)
```

Can any one help on this

Comment: Your desired output complies with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in the `toString` method of `LocalDate`. Just call `LocalDate.toString()` to generate your output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. You already had the date from `LocalDate.ofYearDay(year.toInt, day)`.

You just need to call `.toString` on that as yield will produce a sequence which you wanted:

```
def allDaysForYear(year: Int): Seq[String] = {
  val daysInYear = if(Year.of(year).isLeap) 366 else 365
  for(day <- 1 to daysInYear) yield LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, day).toString
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Just a few minor points - the `month` parameter is not used, the year parameter should ideally be an Int to avoid `.toInt` which could blow up later. Also, `1 to daysInYear` will not produce a `List` so the return type of the function does not match. With some tweaks this code does actually produce what I need :-)

Comment: You're absolutely right @PeterPerháč. Wrote this in a hurry. I'll modify as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java Calendar to compute this for you.
It seems like you wanted the date formatted so I changed the signature

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val calendar = Calendar.getInstance
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

def allDaysForYear(year:Int, month:Int):List[String] = {
  calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1)

  (1 to calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).map(_ => {
    val currentDate = calendar.getTime
    calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, true)
    formatter.format(currentDate)
  }).toList
}
```

Comment: Thank for given me your valuable time to solve my problem

Comment: This Answer uses the troublesome old legacy date-time classes that should be avoided, while the Question asks about the modern java.time classes.

Comment: Actually it didn't, the Question did not ask about the modern java.time classes, it asked about how to "write function to get all dates as list for given month and year".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this one liner that, given a `Year` will return a sequence of `LocalDate`s for each day in the year.

```
def datesInYear(year: Year) = (1 to year.length()).map(year.atDay)
```

It's up to caller to create a `Year`. This is done like so `Year.of(...)`

How this works: `Year` has `length` property that takes care of leap years etc. (no need to do `if( leap ) 355 else 356`) also no need for a for-comprehension, if all we're doing is mapping a bunch of numbers to dates. `Year#atDay` takes an `Int` and returns a `LocalDate` which is exactly the mapping function we need for the `map` call, so no need to construct an anonymous function for the mapping (i.e. `.map(n => year.atDay(n))` is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

couple of ways to handle this. Following code gets rid of leap year explicit handling as well.

If you need a List output

```
def allDaysForYear(year: String , month:String): List[String] = {
val daysInMonth = java.time.YearMonth.of(year.toInt,month.toInt).lengthOfMonth
    for
    {
        day <- (1 to daysInMonth ).toList
        localdate = java.time.LocalDate.of(year.toInt,month.toInt,day).toString
    } yield(localdate)
}
```

output for Feb-2020 year will look like this

```
allDaysForYear("2020","02")

List[String] = List(2020-02-01, 2020-02-02, 2020-02-03, 2020-02-04, 2020-02-05, 2020-02-06, 2020-02-07, 2020-02-08, 2020-02-09, 2020-02-10, 2020-02-11, 2020-02-12, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16, 2020-02-17, 2020-02-18, 2020-02-19, 2020-02-20, 2020-02-21, 2020-02-22, 2020-02-23, 2020-02-24, 2020-02-25, 2020-02-26, 2020-02-27, 2020-02-28, 2020-02-29)
```

if you need a sequence

```
def allDaysForYear(year: String , month:String): Seq[String] = {
        val daysInMonth = java.time.YearMonth.of(year.toInt,month.toInt).lengthOfMonth
        for (day <- 1 to daysInMonth ) yield java.time.LocalDate.of(year.toInt,month.toInt,day).toString
}
```

output for Feb-2020 year will look like this

```
allDaysForYear("2020","02")

Seq[String] = Vector(2020-02-01, 2020-02-02, 2020-02-03, 2020-02-04, 2020-02-05, 2020-02-06, 2020-02-07, 2020-02-08, 2020-02-09, 2020-02-10, 2020-02-11, 2020-02-12, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16, 2020-02-17, 2020-02-18, 2020-02-19, 2020-02-20, 2020-02-21, 2020-02-22, 2020-02-23, 2020-02-24, 2020-02-25, 2020-02-26, 2020-02-27, 2020-02-28, 2020-02-29)
```

if you need a single line output for a given date :

Assuming your date is in format ("YYYY-MM-DD") or ("YYYY-MM") stored under variable dt

```
val daterange = for (day <- 1 to java.time.YearMonth.of(dt.substring(0,4).toInt,dt.substring(5,7).toInt).lengthOfMonth ) yield java.time.LocalDate.of(dt.substring(0,4).toInt,dt.substring(5,7).toInt,day).toString
```

output will look like following for variables

```
val dt = "2020-02" or for variable  val dt = "2020-02-01"/"2020-02-02"or any date for the month 

daterange: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(2020-02-01, 2020-02-02, 2020-02-03, 2020-02-04, 2020-02-05, 2020-02-06, 2020-02-07, 2020-02-08, 2020-02-09, 2020-02-10, 2020-02-11, 2020-02-12, 2020-02-13, 2020-02-14, 2020-02-15, 2020-02-16, 2020-02-17, 2020-02-18, 2020-02-19, 2020-02-20, 2020-02-21, 2020-02-22, 2020-02-23, 2020-02-24, 2020-02-25, 2020-02-26, 2020-02-27, 2020-02-28, 2020-02-29)
```